# Kernel build fails due to withdrawn Nvidia driver package

Tags: 18.04, kernel

I'm trying to build the Ubuntu Bionic kernel 4.15.0-122-generic following the instructions at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel.

It proceeds for quite a while, then tries to download some Nvidia packages that are now missing, possibly because of [security vulnerabilities discovered in them](https://lwn.net/Articles/843249/).

How can I proceed with building the kernel? I do not need the Nvidia drivers, can I disable them somehow?

```
II: dkms-build downloading nvidia-418srv (nvidia-kernel-source-418-server_418.181.07-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.1_amd64.deb)
II: fetching https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/nvidia-kernel-source-418-server_418.181.07-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
grep: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list: No such file or directory
II: fetching http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//pool/restricted/n/nvidia-graphics-drivers-418-server/nvidia-kernel-source-418-server_418.181.07-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
II: fetching http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//pool/main/n/nvidia-graphics-drivers-418-server/nvidia-kernel-source-418-server_418.181.07-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
II: fetching http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//pool/restricted/n/nvidia-graphics-drivers-418-server/nvidia-kernel-source-418-server_418.181.07-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
II: fetching http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//pool/main/n/nvidia-graphics-drivers-418-server/nvidia-kernel-source-418-server_418.181.07-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
EE: nvidia-kernel-source-418-server not found
debian/rules.d/2-binary-arch.mk:112: recipe for target 'install-generic' failed
make: *** [install-generic] Error 1
```

Comment: Include additional info in question via edit not in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around it by disabling Nvidia DKMS:

```
sed -i '/do_dkms_nvidia/ s/true/false/' debian.master/rules.d/amd64.mk
```